# How to style the element that is highlghted when you press tab in firefox?

Tags: css

I thought it would be `:focus` or `:active`, but it does not seem to be the case.

I got rid of the dotted border by setting `outline:none;`, but if click and drag off one of the buttons so that it turns orange and then press tab the newly active element does not get styled like I thought it should.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bh9ah/1/)

How can I style the element that is normally outlined in a dotted outline in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `a` instead of a `div`, that'll do the trick (remove the "div" inside the "a", and style the "a")
Remember to use `display:block` on your `a` to work as a block.
Than the  :active (to work on IE):focus (the rest) and will take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change your code so you're targeting a:active, a:focus. Div:active works but not div:focus because only an anchor can be focused.